# How to add weeknames as x axis values in Matplot R

Tags: r, matplotlib, plot

I have a time series data which I have converted to a matrix (168,11).

```
wc0086 <-  matrix(d0086$c0086ts[1:1848],168,11)
```

Then, I can change the row names to weekdays as follows:

```
time_index1 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 00:00", tz = 'UTC'), to = as.POSIXct("2017-01-08 23:00", tz = 'UTC'), by = "hour")
wdays <- weekdays(time_index1)

wdays <- as.factor(weekdays(time_index1))
row.names(wc0086) <- wdays
```

Then, I am trying to draw a matplot of wc0086.

```
matplot(wc0086, type="l")
```

The problem is that the x-axis showing the the values from 1 to 168 (the number of rows of the matrix. I want to show the weekdays(Monday to Sunday).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
matplot(wc0086, type="l", xaxt='n')
axis(side=1, at=1:168, labels=wdays)
```

This may create an x-axis tick for every day, which you might not want, but you might be able to play with subsetting the `at=` and `labels=` arguments.